# xstream unserialize complex XML to simpler java with Converter

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xstream

I have surely a problem of understanding of Xstream converter.

I have a pretty complex XML coming from legacy back office application and a just want to convert this one into a simpler java class or a Map with Converter.

1. *I do not want to marshal to XML, just unmarshal*
2. *I do not want to use annotation, just KISS*

My XML is like

```
<root>
    <agent>
        <id>123456789</id>
        <name>GABIN</name>
        <forname>Jean</forname>
        <unit>
            <legacyReference>AA</legacyReference>
            <name>SAN ANTONIO</name>
            <legacyName>SA</legacyName>
            <address>
                <number>1</number>
                <street>Sesam street</street>
                <city>NoWhere</city>
                <legacyID>AAZE-56</legacyID>
            </address>
            <legacyStructurBlablabla>
                <type>OFFICE</type>
                <data>
                    <foo>BAR</foo> 
                </data>
            </legacyStructurBlablabla>
            <...>
        </unit>
        <...> 
    </agent>
</root>
```

My destination class is very simple

```
class Agent {
    String id;
    String name;
    String forname;
    String unitName;
    String unitType;
    <...>

}
```

My main method looks like

```
xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/agent.xml") ;
xStream.alias("root", Map.class);
xStream.alias("agent", Agent.class);
xStream.registerConverter(new ResultConverter());
xStream.registerConverter(new AgentConverter());
xStream.ignoreUnknownElements();

Object obj = xStream.fromXML(stream);
```

I don't understand how to step down in favor of another converter.

```
public class ResultConverter implements Converter {

...


public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
        UnmarshallingContext context) {
    Map<String, Object> agents = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    while( reader.hasMoreChildren() ) {
        reader.moveDown();
        // HOW I DO TO STEP DOWN IN FAVOR OF Agent CONVERTER ?
        reader.moveUp();
    }
    return agents;
}
```

I didn't see Xstream scrolled dow the thierarchy to activate my AgentConverter.

I surely missing the point

**EDIT**

Xstream may be not thr right tool for this.
I would use xmlbeam, according to Cfx advise.
XMLBeam *projects* the XML to a Java Class according to XPATH mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you want the xml structure not to be reflected in your Java class. If you stick to XStream, I have no solution. But there is an [alternative framework](http://xmlbeam.org) that was made to solve exactly this issue. It uses annotations, but IMHO does not violate the KISS principle.
Here is an example:

```
public interface Agent {

@XBRead("/root/agent/id")
String getId();

@XBRead("/root/agent/name")
String getName();

@XBRead("/root/agent/forename")
String getForname();

@XBRead("/root/agent/unit/name")
String getUnitName();

@XBRead("/root/agent/unit/legacyStructurBlablabla/type")
String getUnitType();
```

}

You will define interfaces instead of classes, but the instances of these interfaces are useable just like POJOs. (with toString(), equals(), hashCode,...).
Creating instances of these interfaces is like this:

```
Agent agent = new XBProjector().io().stream(stream).read(Agent.class);
```

Comment: Nice answer. You're right, it might be the right solution for my problem. I will try http://xmlbeam.org/. Thanks

Comment: But do I have to use an intermediate interface to support list of items ?

as public interface AgentList {
@XBRead("/root/agent")
public List<Agent> getAgents();
}

Comment: Yes, but you may use a trick: Reuse your Agent interface and add the  getAgents() method just to the Agent interface itself. This is not plain OO, but works well.

Comment: I'm very pleased to hear that. Thank you for trying it out. Feel free to contact me (via github or project site) for further support.   There is much more, eg. dynamic projections or creating XML via XPath.